# Multiple adjective word order for phrase with “of” and “for”

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

I am trying to translate this sentence and am having a hard time deciding where all the adjectives go:

> The Airborne family of personnel oxygen systems for military jumpers also includes: a.b.c...
>
> La famille des systèmes d’Airborne d’oxygène de parachute du personnel pour les gréeurs militaires comprend également: a.b.c...

Airborne is the proper name of the company. I was thinking of moving d'Airborne to the end of the phrase, but then the impression might be that they were military jumpers from the Airborne company, and that is not right. Airborne makes the family of oxygen systems.

Can anyone help me with translating this little phrase?

Answer (score 1):

- While the latter is also used, I would recommend *gamme* instead of *famille* when talking about a range of products.
- If *systèmes d'oxygène* is unclear, you can add *d'apport* to make clear what they are about.
- *Oxygène de parachute* doesn't work, the oxygen is not for the parachute but for the jumper.
- *Du personnel* means "of the staff", not what you want here. "Personal systems" can be translated as *système individuels* or *systèmes personnels*.
- *Gréeurs* is a rare word and is related to sailing boats, irrelevant here.

I would then suggest:

> *La gamme Airborne de systèmes [d'apport] d'oxygène pour parachutistes militaires comprend aussi...*

While *parachutiste militaire* is sometimes used, better to apply the adjective *militaire* to the range of products. If you also want to state these systems are personal, you might also write:

> *La gamme militaire Airborne de systèmes personnels [d'apport] d'oxygène pour parachutistes comprend aussi...*

Answer (score 0):

Les systèmes d'oxygène personnel de la famille Airborne pour les parachutistes militaires (parachute jumping I take it?) incluent également : ...

Answer (score -1):

Both

> La famille des systèmes d’oxygène à personnel **(d')Airborne**
>   pour les parachutistes militaires comprend également: a.b.c...

and

> La famille des systèmes d’oxygène à personnel pour les
>   parachutistes militaires **(d')Airborne** comprend également: a.b.c...

look good to me.

The second one is indeed more ambiguous, but in the context, the reader will obviously understand that the jumpers don't belong to Airborne, so I wouldn't worry...

A few notes :

- You added *parachute* to the French sentence while it was not in the original one - this might alter the meaning slightly.
- I found occurrences of *parachute à personnel*, but none of *système d'oxygène à personnel*, so this translation might be subpar. Is *personnel oxygen systems* really a thing in the military field or was the concept coinded by the company? Knowing that could help.
- It looks like *sauteur* is not a thing and *gréeur* a completely different animal ([rigger](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26541120)), hence *parachutiste*.

Comment: Downvoter(s), care to explain?